# setting null value for defaultTTL for azure cosmos bicep

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

Hi I have tried to turn off the TTL for Azure cosmos. I know that it could be turn off by Not include defaultTtl in the code. However I have conditional deployment, I have a loop that check for tenant name to create cosmos container, if it equal to 'int999' then set defaultTtl to 604800 otherwise turn off TTL.
I tried to set it to null but the pipeline run failed, it has a very general error message
"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details"

[image]

Here is my bicep code

```
resource containers 'Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases/containers@2021-06-15' = [for i in range(0, length(tenants)): {
  name: '${databases[i].name}/messages'
  properties: {
    resource: {
      id: 'messages'
      partitionKey: {
        paths: [
          '/organisationId'
        ]
      }
      defaultTtl: tenants[i] == 'int999' ? 604800 : null
    }
  }
}]
```

I feel weird cause in the azure documents, defaultTTL should accept null value https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/time-to-live. However it seem I face a syntax error when set it to null here. Could anyone help please. Thanks

Note: Please note that set defaultTTL to -1 is not acceptable solution for my case. we want to turn off the TTL completely.

Comment: have you tried `json('null')` ?

Comment: You could also check error details from azure portal: `resource group -> deployments`

Comment: @Thomas I have tried using json('null') but it does not work.
If I remove the null value and put an valid number (Ex 1000) then the pipeline work fine.

Comment: The error details is :"Bad request -One of the specified inputs is invalid".

Comment: and if you try without the property does it work ?

Comment: Thank @Thomas . Do you mean remove the defaultTTL ? if so then Yep it will work but as I mention above, I need a conditional deployment, it will check if tenant name is 'int999' then set defaultTTL to 604800,  otherwise defaultTTL will be null. You can take a look at my code to see that.

Comment: you could try to merge the properties based on a condition: `union(defaultProperties, {defaultTtl: 604800 })` or something like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried as well the `null` or `json('null')` and it didnt work.

Here you need to conditionally add the `defaultTtl` property based on a condition.
This bicep file defines some default properties and add the `defaultTtl` if required:

```bicep
param cosmosdbAccountName string
param databaseName string
param tenant string = 'int999'

// reference to the cosmos db account
resource cosmosdbAccount 'Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts@2021-06-15' existing = {
  name: cosmosdbAccountName
}

// reference to the cosmos db database
resource database 'Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases@2021-06-15' existing = {
  name: databaseName
  parent: cosmosdbAccount
}

// Create default properties for the container
var defaultResource = {
  id: 'messages'
  partitionKey: {
    paths: [
      '/organisationId'
    ]
  }
}

// Create the container
resource container 'Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases/containers@2021-06-15' = {
  name: 'messages'
  parent: database
  properties: {
    // Add the default ttl if needed
    resource: union(defaultResource, tenant == 'int999' ? {
      defaultTtl: 604800
    } : {})
  }
}
```

Comment: is there any easier way than this? what if when we have to set multiple properties based on their own conditions?